# how to get Table sent by scalate ssp in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, scala, scalate, ssp, scalatra-sbt

I work with framework scalatra , I declare my array in this manner up the page .ssp

```
<% @ val table_activity: Array [String]%>
```

usually if I want to extract data from middle of the page .ssp :

```
<%  for ( x <- 0 to table_activity.length-1)    {   %>  

       <tr> 
            <td>     
                 <%=table_activity(x) %>
            </td>   
       </tr>    

<%  }   %>
```

but in my case I want to manage my data in javascript function and I have no idea how to do it!!
if you have idea please help me

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you could serialize your data as json and then access it from your javascript code. If you have never done that before, there are several libraries available for scala: http://engineering.ooyala.com/blog/comparing-scala-json-libraries